# ILNumerics: Does this also in the Net Framework 3.5.?

Tags: ilnumerics

I wanted to ask whether the ILNumerics library for the .Net Framework 3.5 is available.
I can with my project where I would like to use the library has not upgrade on that .Net Framework 4 or 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

ILNumerics is designed for .NET framework version 4.0. On mono at least version 2.10 is recommended (http://ilnumerics.net/specifications.html)

May I ask why you don't want to upgrade the .NET framework?

Comment: The application on which we want to use them ILNumerics, has hardware limitations. The older devices where we have constituted the software install is not enough disk space to the .Net Framework 4.0.

So there is no way to get to ILNumerics 3.5?